# String concatenation with haskell state monad

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming, state

I need to wrap my head around the state monad in haskell and I have some problems with that.
The task is to implement a function *countConcat* which concatenates string with the state monad and a function *extractCC* which gets the result of this function.

So `extractCC ((return 0) >>= countConcat "a" >>= countConcat "b" >>= countConcat "c")` would yield (3,"abc")

As far as I understand countConcat would be kind of a manipulator function and extractCC should contain some kind of runState, right?

Any tipps or ressources getting me into the right direction are highly appreciated.
(I´ve been through the wiki and the learnyouahaskell section, but still feeling quite stupid with this)

Comment: Try writing it without using State first, i.e. as a function `String -> (Int, String) -> (Int, String)`. Then look at State explanation again to see how that function maps to the monad. Also the initial state would be `(0, "")` (in the first `return`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, i´ve already tried modeling the function without State, which was quite easy. My problem is more fitting to the signature of countConcat and implementing the bin operator to work on State chaining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this first

```
concat' :: String -> State (Int,String) ()
concat' s = do
  (c,st) <- get
  put (c+1, st ++ s)
```

You can run this by

```
> runState ( concat' "A" >> concat' "B" >> concat' "C" ) (0,"")
((),(3,"ABC"))
```

I think if you understand state monad you can modify the above example for your need.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Satvik I was able to solve the Problem. Here is my final solution:

```
newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (a,s)}

instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State (\s -> (x,s))
    (State h) >>= f = State (\s -> let (a, newState) = h s
                                       (State g)     = f a  
                                   in  g newState)

                      -- Save new state
countConcat :: String -> Int -> State String Int
countConcat s i =do
  st <- get -- get current string
  put ((st ++ s)) -- put conc. string
  return (i+1) -- return new counter


extractCC f =(runState f ("")) --run the function, staring with an empty string


-- Helper from the wiki
put newState = State $ \_ -> ((), newState)
get = State $ \st -> (st, st)

-- extractCC ((return 0) >>= countConcat "a" >>= countConcat "b" >>= countConcat "c")
-- (3,"abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `first` combinator from `Control.Arrow`, then:

```
countConcat :: String -> State (String,Int) ()
countConcat s = modify ((<> s) *** (+1))
```

Comment: This was very alien to me, so I read alot about the Arrow type in Haskell. I think I understand the *** now, but I am not able to run it because of the <> , do I need a special import here ?